# How to better implement a second level of login in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My ASP.NET MVC web application project requires to have a user login and then after successfully logging-in the user should select one of the clinics that he/she is a member of. I added a custom attribute in FilterConfig to detect if current user have a clinic selected.
I'm storing the Id of the selected clinic in session because all throughout the application, CRUD operations, data, images, etc. will be dependent on which clinic the user selected.

Also, if user is only a member of one clinic, no selection needed. User should/will always be a member of at least one clinic.

This is how I implemented it.
My question is if I implemented it efficiently, performance-wise.
My concerns are regarding storing the clinicId in session, and the trips to database when checking the user's list of clinic.
Is there a better way to do this?

My ApplicationUser model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // parts redacted

    public ICollection<Clinic> Clinics { get; set; }
    // parts redacted
}
```

My Clinic model:

```
public class Clinic
{
    // parts redacted

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

My custom attribute:

```
public class SessionClinicAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private bool _filter;

    public SessionClinicAttribute(bool filter = true)
    {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        if (_filter && !ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login?returnUrl=" +
            filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
            return;
        }

        if (_filter && ctx.Session["ClinicId"] == null)
        {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/ClinicLogin?returnUrl=" +
                filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));

            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Portions of my AccountController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [SessionClinic (false)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var user = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Clinics).Single(u => u.UserName == model.Email);
                if (user.Clinics.Count > 1)
                {
                    Session["ClinicId"] = null;
                    return RedirectToAction("ClinicLogin", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl});
                }

                Session["ClinicId"] = user.Clinics.ToList()[0].Id;
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            // parts redacted
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [SessionClinic(false)]
    public ActionResult ClinicLogin(long clinicId, string returnUrl)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Clinics).Single(u => u.Id == userId);
        if (user.Clinics.Any(c => c.Id == clinicId))
            Session["ClinicId"] = clinicId;
        else
            return View("Error");

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered making the clinic part of the route? that way you can remove it from the session making the selection stateless. The clinics permitted could be stored in the authentication token when using a form of claim based auth. The first will provide unique urls a user could bookmark and be stateless and with multiple windows/tabs.. The second to allow users to switch between multiple clinics instantly and allows you to authorize users without having to go to the DB all the time. JWT comes to mind: https://jwt.io/